# Cannot write the following Java expression in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to write in kotlin this java statement:

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));
```

I have tried the following:

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(((array[i] and 0xFF.toByte()) or 0x100.toByte()).toInt()).substring(1, 3))
```

The kotlin "and" and "or" are from importing:

```
import kotlin.experimental.and
import kotlin.experimental.or
```

I believe the problem is in the .toByte() function which is not needed in Java, but Kotlin obliges to it to compile.

What could I do so an equivalent code to the one in Java is written in Kotlin?

Comment: what type is `array`?

Comment: @MattTimmermans, it's a ByteArray.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

When pasting your java code in Android studio, it automatically converts

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));
```

to

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(array[i] and 0xFF or 0x100).substring(1, 3))
```

which is different than your kotlin code and IDE shows no compile time error, at least.

Explanation: What you were doing is you're taking integer as `0xFF` then converting it to byte using `.toByte()` and then, again coverting it to integer as `.toInt()` which is redundant.

Comment: Thanks @LalitFauzdar, but I had already tried that, and in my case it does show compile time error.

Comment: There are these 3 ones: Type mismatch: inferred type is Byte but Int was expected, The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Byte and that same one again.

Comment: @user2638180 the only thing that can give such an error is your array, share the code containing it, what is its type?

Comment: Hi, I got to find the answer in another stackoverflow question, thanks for your help any way, I'm answering now.

Answer (score 1):

It's faster if you write it like this:

```
array[i].toInt().let {
    sb.append( "0123456789abcdef".charAt((it ushr 4) and 15) )
    sb.append( "0123456789abcdef".charAt(it and 15) )
}
```

That avoids the creation of two temporary strings.

Answer (score 0):

Expression must be written this way to work:

```
sb.append(Integer.toHexString(array[i].toInt() and 0xFF or 0x100).substring(1, 3))
```

Comment: As obvious, the array was the culprit. See, this is why it's encouraged to share the whole code because we can't help in your code without your code.